# html equivalent to c# group box

Tags: html

I'm currently trying to rewrite a program i have written in C# (windows forms application) as a website.
The program needs to check in which state some radio buttons are. In the desktop version they are organised using group boxes.

Is there a html equivalent to group boxes?

I want to avoid giving all radios a name which is a combination of a fixed prefix and an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same `name` attribute for the buttons in a group; they can each have a distinct `id` to tell them apart.  (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there is an easier way to group the buttons than using the name property. Than I have to do it like that. Ok.

Comment: What did you imagine would be easier?

Comment: Grouping them. I C# I create a group box, put the buttons inside and they are under the same "name". Then I do this n times and the groups don't affect each other. My plan was to do something similar in html and js, but if nothing like that exists, I have to use a list to keep track of all names. It's ok as well.